# Drecrease size of MovieClip in relation to distance, any suggestion? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, distance, movieclip

I have a ball that will be kicked by the player, it is a  movieclip and I want it to get smaller little by little as it gets away from the original spot, a AS3 tween perhaps? This is the code moving the ball:

```
speed=10;
var ease:int = 100;
var gravity:Number = 0.5;
function moveBall()
{  
  var targetX:Number = mouseX;
var targetY:Number = mouseY;
var angle = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX);
bola.x =  mouseX + Math.cos(angle);
bola.y =  mouseY + Math.sin(angle) ;
ballRotation = true;
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
```

Thanks a lot for your patience and help!

Comment: Assuming your ball travels upwards along the y access to be 'father away',  you could just set the scale properties of the ball based on the y position as it travels along.

Comment: Thanks a lot again LondonDrugs! by the way the code above is making the ball travel from the starting point to the mouse position in a single step, I need to see the ball while it travels,  I dont want to use the onenterframe stuff since it makes my code trigger a los variables many times, should I use a tween instead, like tweening from Ball.x to mouseposition.x, would that be possible?

Comment: you can have multiple onEnterFrame handlers on a project.  It's the most fluid way for this sort of thing.  Tween classes use enterframe events under the hood too.   You could use a Tweening class and every tick set the scale appropriately.

Comment: Most tweening engines though are based off of time and not distance.  What I mean by that is, with a tween you tell the ball to go from point A to point B over x seconds - as opposed to going from point A to point B at a certain velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tweenlite/tweenmax, you can get a pretty realistic ball getting kicked with this code:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
TweenPlugin.activate([BezierPlugin]);

ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kickBall);
function kickBall(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenMax.to(ball,2,{scaleX:0,scaleY:0,bezier:[{x:400, y:-250}, {x:315, y:200}]});
}
```

Obviously you can tweak those values as you please.

example: http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/ball.swf

Comment: Thanks a lot LondonDrugs, really appreciated man, will try that!!! Hey Ronnie thanks for that pal, seems to be really good judging by the code sequence, I guess I could change any of the "destination" parameters to my Mouse position, am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you can certainly use the mouse coords in there..you can download tweenlite/max at http://www.greensock.com, just download and unzip the com folder to your working directory

Comment: Do keep in mind that the use of TweenMax (or any of the greensock stuff) requires a license if your project charges the end user any kind of fee (including in game transactions).  There are similar tweening libraries that don't have this restriction if it would be an issue for you

Comment: Thanks a Lot Ronnie and LondonDrugs! Do not worry pal I'm not even close to be good enough to start charging a fee for my games,  if I sale such  an amateur artwork probably I would be the one paying a fee to not get beaten!  Have a great night friends!